# SwiftyJSON for loop Return all Index Data

Tags: ios, json, for-loop, get-request

I'm testing how to implement a JSON web API for an application I'm working on.  Apparently, SwiftyJSON is a really awesome module I can use to simplify all my JSON calls.

So far, I've gotten the Calling code working, but as for printing output, im still having trouble.

I'm attempting to return ALL the data under the "user" index, but theres so many arrays within array and im new to JSON its all very confusing

CODE:

```
let urlPath = "http://api.randomuser.me/"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        let json = JSON(jsonResult)
        let count: Int? = json["results"].array?.count
        print("found \(count!) result")

        let results = json["results"]

        for (key, subJson) in results{
            if let title = subJson["user"]["gender"].string{
                print(title)
            }
        }

    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("Something went wrong.")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

})
task.resume()
```

Feel free visit the URL to view the structure of the JSON array.

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

I thought this might work:

```
for (key, subJson) in results{
    for (key, user) in subJson{
        print(user[key])
    }
}
```

But print(user[key]) = NULL.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you just have to change `subJson["user"]["gender"]` to `subJson["gender"]` since the key `user` is stored in `key` and `subJson` contains the value, e.g. the actual user.

Comment: subJson["user"]["gender"] returns "male", which is correct.  But I'm wanting to return all key-value pairs nested under "user". So like user > gender, user > name, user > email, user > username, etc.  Please visit http://api.randomuser.me/ and you'll see what I mean.